# Exception: SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not get home directory to locate service definition file

Tags: php, postgresql, zend-framework, pdo

I got this error message, but searched online without any result.
Basically I tried to use PHP zendframework 1, to connect PostgreSQL database(using php_pdo_pgsql extension). Under Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract, it finds the extension loaded and also the PDO driver is available. But at the next step making connection step, I get the exception above: Exception: SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not get home directory to locate service definition file.

I double checked the config.xml file, everything seems correct.

```
 <db>
        <adapter>pdo_pgsql</adapter>
        <params>
          <service>postgresql-x64-10</service>
          <port>5432</port>
          <host>127.0.0.1</host>
          <username>postgres</username>
          <password>password</password>
          <dbname>postgres</dbname>
          <charset>utf8</charset>
        </params>          
        ....
```

I can run PostgreSQL on local computer using either pgAdmin or command line without any issue.

Also according to https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/libpq-pgservice.html
I tried to add the path of pg_service.conf under share folder as both user and system path,but without success.

Does anyone else encounter this issue? So what does the error indicates and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you didn't update PostgreSQL to the latest bugfix release [like you should](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning).

This is [bug 14872](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/20171025200457.1471.34504@wrigleys.postgresql.org) and was fixed with [commit db6986f47c9531628d151d6bf760a2fe1214b19d](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=commitdiff;h=db6986f47c9531628d151d6bf760a2fe1214b19d).

What triggers the bug is that the home directory of the user running the PostgreSQL client code does not exist.